# How do you re-size Facebook plugin comment (fb-comments) with angular on window resize?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, facebook, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do you re-size a Facebook plugin comment on window/browser re-size?

I would like to have the fb-comment div to re-size to the same size as the parent element when the browser window re-sizes.

```
<div id="socialDiv" class="col-lg-12">
...
  <div class="fb-comments" data-href="{{vote.link}}" data-width="{{socialWidth}}" data-numposts="5"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the controller you will need to setup a bind to the $window 'resize'. Then create a function that will select the fb-comments iframe span element and re-size it.

```
angular.element($window).bind('resize', function(){
  $('.fb-comments iframe,.fb-comments span:first-child').css({'width':$('#socialDiv').width()});
});
```